# Alternate Alphabet Depending on List Length

Tags: python

I want to list names and print them so that each name has a letter just before it.

For example:

```
a : John
b : Sam
d : Fiona
etc...
```

I managed to do this with:

```
import string
player_names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Nami', 'Zoro', 'Luffy', 'Kaiden', 'Usopp', 'FRANKY', 'Gaien', 'Ichigo', 'Izumi', 'Rukia', 'Yagami', 'Goku', 'Jessy', 'Heisenberg', 'Nami', 'Robin', 'Sunny', 'Sanji', 'Kirito', 'Bebop', 'Duffy', 'Luster', 'Yugi', 'Haitham', 'Jamal']

#print (len(player_names))
#print(len(string.ascii_lowercase))

chars_names = [char + ' : ' + player_name for char, player_name in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, player_names)]
print('\n'.join(chars_names))
```

But as you can see since the length of ASCII_lowercase is 26 and we have 27 names; that last name doesn't get printed.

I want to proceed with each subsequent name after the 26th one having a double letter for it's listing.

For example:

```
a: John
b: Sam
.....
aa: Lamis
ab: Sandy
```

And so on...

Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a function that I use for these cases:

```
import string
def base26_count(value: int):
    s = ''
    while value > 0:
        mod = (value - 1) % 26
        s = string.ascii_lowercase[mod] + s
        value = (value - 1) // 26
    return s
```

It can be used to count in letters in the same way you describe, it returns a value of `''` for an input of `0`, `'a'` for `1`, `'aa'` for `27` and so on...

To use it in your use-case, we can do something like this:

```
player_names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Nami', 'Zoro', 'Luffy', 'Kaiden', 'Usopp', 'FRANKY', 'Gaien', 'Ichigo', 'Izumi', 'Rukia', 'Yagami', 'Goku', 'Jessy', 'Heisenberg', 'Nami', 'Robin', 'Sunny', 'Sanji', 'Kirito', 'Bebop', 'Duffy', 'Luster', 'Yugi', 'Haitham', 'Jamal']
for i, name in enumerate(player_names):
    print('{}: {}'.format(base26_count(i + 1), name))
```

The output:

```
a: John
b: Sam
c: Nami
d: Zoro
e: Luffy
f: Kaiden
g: Usopp
h: FRANKY
i: Gaien
j: Ichigo
k: Izumi
l: Rukia
m: Yagami
n: Goku
o: Jessy
p: Heisenberg
q: Nami
r: Robin
s: Sunny
t: Sanji
u: Kirito
v: Bebop
w: Duffy
x: Luster
y: Yugi
z: Haitham
aa: Jamal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a longer list with all the ascii possibilities:

```
import string
player_names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Nami', 'Zoro', 'Luffy', 'Kaiden', 'Usopp', 'FRANKY', 'Gaien', 'Ichigo', 'Izumi', 'Rukia', 'Yagami', 'Goku', 'Jessy', 'Heisenberg', 'Nami', 'Robin', 'Sunny', 'Sanji', 'Kirito', 'Bebop', 'Duffy', 'Luster', 'Yugi', 'Haitham', 'Jamal']
keys = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
for i in range(len(player_names) // 26):
    keys += [string.ascii_lowercase[i] + c for c in string.ascii_lowercase]
chars_names = [char + ' : ' + player_name for char, player_name in zip(keys, player_names)]
print('\n'.join(chars_names))
```

Output:

```
a : John
b : Sam
c : Nami
d : Zoro
e : Luffy
f : Kaiden
g : Usopp
h : FRANKY
i : Gaien
j : Ichigo
k : Izumi
l : Rukia
m : Yagami
n : Goku
o : Jessy
p : Heisenberg
q : Nami
r : Robin
s : Sunny
t : Sanji
u : Kirito
v : Bebop
w : Duffy
x : Luster
y : Yugi
z : Haitham
aa : Jamal
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a sample list which will generate your respective sequence and then combine both the lists.

```
import string
from string import ascii_lowercase
player_names = ['John', 'Sam', 'Nami', 'Zoro', 'Luffy', 'Kaiden', 'Usopp', 'FRANKY', 'Gaien', 'Ichigo', 'Izumi', 'Rukia', 'Yagami', 'Goku', 'Jessy', 'Heisenberg', 'Nami', 'Robin', 'Sunny', 'Sanji', 'Kirito', 'Bebop', 'Duffy', 'Luster', 'Yugi', 'Haitham', 'Jamal']
custom_list= list(ascii_lowercase) +[l1+l2 for l1,l2 in zip(string.ascii_lowercase,player_names) for l2 in ascii_lowercase]
#print('\n'.join(custom_list))
print(dict(zip(custom_list,player_names)))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'John', 'b': 'Sam', 'c': 'Nami', 'd': 'Zoro', 'e': 'Luffy', 'f': 'Kaiden', 'g': 'Usopp', 'h': 'FRANKY', 'i': 'Gaien', 'j': 'Ichigo', 'k': 'Izumi', 'l': 'Rukia', 'm': 'Yagami', 'n': 'Goku', 'o': 'Jessy', 'p': 'Heisenberg', 'q': 'Nami', 'r': 'Robin', 's': 'Sunny', 't': 'Sanji', 'u': 'Kirito', 'v': 'Bebop', 'w': 'Duffy', 'x': 'Luster', 'y': 'Yugi', 'z': 'Haitham', 'aa': 'Jamal'}
```